# RethinkDB get all and order with index

Tags: rethinkdb, reql

I have an object like this:

```
Company {
  Enable bool
  Pro bool
  Type int
  Categories []int
}
```

So, how can I make query to retrieve all objects that Enable=true, Categories contains, for example, "1" and order by Pro and Type.
I have more than 200,000 records so I have to to that efficient with indexes.

I try to use this:

```
r.db("test_main").table("companies").indexCreate("ListAll", function(comp) {
    return comp("Categories").map(function(cat) {
        return [ comp("Pro"), comp("CompType"), comp("Enabled"), cat  ];
    });
}, {multi: true})

r.db("test_main").table("companies").between([false, 0, true, 1],
  [r.maxval, r.maxval, true, 1], {index:"ListAll"}).orderBy({index:r.desc("ListAll")}).limit(100)
```

But categories doesn't match.

Comment: Did you end up figuring this out?

Comment: Yes, I use elasticsearch for search data and rethinkdb for persistent storage.